estimation of updated proprotion
I would need your advice on the following problem.
Activity of transcription of recording in data is done by human and could lead to error and mistakes. we want to controle this activity to be with less errors. if it appears that we have a higher errors we should check all the recordings and correct them.
we have more or less a population of recordings of 10.000 recordings.
we sample 300 recordings and check whether there were errors in trasncription of these recordings.
5% of recordings with errors is not acceptable in the population.
3% can be acceptable in the population.
using these data and some confidence, I identified that 4% errors can be a cutoff above which we can trigger a full population check for errors correction. below 4% error rate, I will not do any check and accept the activity with limited error rate.
Imagine I observed in the sample of 300 recording an error rate of 6%.
my objective at end is not to check all population data which is expensive, I want to select a proportion of the population to correct that give me enough evidence that the error rate is controlled below 4%.
any suggestion how to identify this proportion of the population to correct in case of 6% error is observed in the sample?
thank you
